# Java: Parse a string and store in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, python, sqlite, parsing

I'm new to JAVA and writing an android app which receives a message from a python script in the form of tuple of tuples converted into string: 
"((1,2,3,4),(a,b,c,d))"

I need to save this data in SQLite database in android with (1,2,3,4) and (a,b,c,d) being different rows under same table. I'm trying to do this by converting the string to Arraylist < Arraylist< String > > using replace and split in Java but this method does not look the best to me.

Is there any other way this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to extract strings that you need by using a regex.

Assuming you need each strings with those two brackets, following regex will do the job.

```
\((\w\,?)*\)
```

Here is an example code.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String regex = "\\((\\w\\,?)*\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String str = "((1,2,3,4),(a,b,c,d))";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        // you can extract strings here.
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to solve my issue with regex.